# How to implement stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: r

In stochastic gradient descent, we often consider the objective function as a sum of a finite number of functions:

```
             f(x)=∑fi(x) where i = 1 : n
```

At each iteration, rather than computing the gradient `∇f(x)`, stochastic gradient descent randomly samples `i` at uniform and computes `∇fi(x)` instead.

The insight is that stochastic gradient descent uses `∇fi(x)` as an unbiased estimator of `∇f(x)`.

We update `x` as :        `x:=x−η∇fi(x)` where `η` is the learning step.

I found difficulties implementing this in R for an optimization problem.

```
stoc_grad<-function(){
  # set up a stepsize
  alpha = 0.1

  # set up a number of iteration
  iter = 30

  # define the objective function f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
  objFun = function(x) return(sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x))

  # define the gradient of f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
  gradient_1 = function(x) return(1/2*sqrt(2+x))
  gradient_2 = function(x) return(1/2*sqrt(3+x))
  gradient_3 = function(x) return(1/2*sqrt(1+x))

  x = 1

  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = numeric(iter)

  # gradient descent method to find the minimum
  for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    x = x - alpha*gradient_1(x)
    x = x - alpha*gradient_2(x)
    x = x - alpha*gradient_3(x)
    x.All[i] = x
    print(x)
  }

  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
  plot(x.All, type = "l")  

}
```

Algorithm pseudo-code : 
[Find pseudo-code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KPmN.png)

In fact , I want to test this algorithm for optimization of a test function like Three-hump camel function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization

Other example :

[image]

Comment: You can use math typesetting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a simple typo in your gradient functions' code or simple differentiation mistake. Change the gradients with below alternatives:

```
  gradient_1 = function(x) return(1/(2*sqrt(2+x)))
  gradient_2 = function(x) return(1/(2*sqrt(3+x)))
  gradient_3 = function(x) return(1/(2*sqrt(1+x)))
```

Because $\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+x})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}\neq \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{2}$ as implied by yours.

And, for this optimization function, it's highly possible that you get NaN's (probably in R) or imaginary numbers soon because of the square roots. Your objective function is defined over $x\in [-1,\infty)$, so do boundary checks in your updates.

For converting your batch update to stochastic update, treating as if each of your components are from different data samples' loss contributions, we have (in its simplest form):

```
for(i in seq_len(iter)){
        r = runif(1)
        if(r < 1/3)
            x = x - alpha*gradient_1(x)
        else if(r < 2/3)
            x = x - alpha*gradient_2(x)
        else
            x = x - alpha*gradient_3(x)

        x.All[i] = x
        print(x)
    }
```

which also converges to your optimum via some zig-zags.

Comment: The problem with stochastic descent is that i didn't find any package for optimization. Your remark is correct but hadn't resolved the problem.

Comment: gunes : I updated the post , look the other example .

Comment: @user246160 I've added the updated for loop; it's just a matter of randomization.

Comment: Thank you mister , but what is //  seq_len(iter) // in your code ?

Comment: it’s the same as in your code, number of optimization iterations.

Comment: Thank you a lot . How can i change my code to fit multivariate function such : objFun = function (x,y) return((x^2+y-11)^2+(x+y^2-7)^2)
  
  # define the gradient of f(x) 
  # Note we don't split up the gradient here
  gradient <- function(x , y) {
    
    result <- c(4*x*(x^2+y-11)+2*(x+y^2-7),2*(x^2 + y - 11 )+4*y*(x+y^2-7))
    
    return(result)
  }

Comment: You can split it again, first summands go to gradient_1, second summands go to gradient_2, i.e. smth like, grad_1 = c(4*x*(x^2+y-11), 2*(x^2 + y - 11 ))

Comment: Not this , i can't retrieve the optimum point in that case which a vector of 2 variables. A problem with x.All = numeric(iter)

Comment: To store Xs values we are using an array because we have a simple variable. For (x,y) i need a multidemensional array.

Comment: Just store y's in y.All (or a MD array as you said). Try it a bit, and if you can't do it, post it as a separate question, since the essential idea here is the randomization of the choice of gradients to use.

Comment: Yes ! I'm trying . Thank you a lot for your valuable help & sorry if i disturbed you :)

Comment: @user246160 no problem. I see that you already posted another one, which is good, since you can get fresh attention on your new problem.